# Use waitKey in order pause and play video

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a `VideoCapture` in OpenCV, I can successfully display a given video. What I want to do now is to pause and play by pressing a key (optional which one as long as it works). I have been reading about `waitKey` but there is something about this whole thing I don't get (ASCII) and how to bind keys. What I understand it is used to let `highgui` process but can also be used for other purposes?

If it is hard/impossible to pause a video and start it again I would be happy with just a delay when key is pressed.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 21):

With reference to [OpenCV Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7) for `cv::waitKey(delay)`, when `delay <= 0` will cause to the function to wait infinitely for a key event.

Here is a sample Python script to display frames captured from computer's webcam. When `q` is pressed, the loop is exited. However, if `p` is pressed, the display pauses until any other key is pressed:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # getting video from webcam
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, img = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow("Frame",img)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q'):
        break
    if key == ord('p'):
        cv2.waitKey(-1) #wait until any key is pressed
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 3):

You dont need anything like binding keys. I have written a sample code which will play/pause the video whenever you press **"p"**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    bool playVideo = true;
    VideoCapture cap(argv[1]);
    if(!cap.isOpened())
    {
        cout<<"Unable to open video "<<argv[1]<<"\n";
        return 0;
    }
    Mat frame;
    while(1)
    {
        if(playVideo)
            cap >> frame;
        if(frame.empty())
        {
            cout<<"Empty Frame\n";
            return 0;
        }
        imshow("Video",frame);
        char key = waitKey(5);
        if(key == 'p')
            playVideo = !playVideo; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe the flag `playVideo` is not necessary. `waitKey(0)` will pause indefinitely, so it will block your while loop until a key is pressed. Documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey).

Comment: yes waitKey(0) will pause indefinitely but in this case  you will have to press a key for every frame to be displayed

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem as you before. I solved it in Python instead of C++, but I think the logic behind is same.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('my.avi')

while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff

    if not ret:
        break

    if key == ord('p'):

        while True:

            key2 = cv2.waitKey(1) or 0xff
            cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

            if key2 == ord('p'):
                break

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    if key == 27: 
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pause and play with `p` use

```
if(cv::waitKey(1) == 'p')
    while(cv::waitKey(1) != 'p');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pause and unpause the video with the same key (e.g. 'Space'), and to exit the video by <kbd>Esc</kbd> even if it's paused then you can do the following:

```
enum Keys {ESC = 27, SPACE = 32};

cv::Mat newFrame;
bool stopVideo = false;

while(video.read(newFrame) && !stopVideo)
{
    cv::imshow("video", newFrame);

    switch(cv::waitKey(25))
    {
        case SPACE:
            while(true)
            {
                int k = cv::waitKey(0);
                if (k == SPACE)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if (k == ESC)
                {
                    stopVideo = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;

        case ESC:
            stopVideo = true;
            break;
    }
}
```