# Usage of ord('q') and 0xFF

Tags: python, opencv

I am not able to understand the following code snippet-

```
if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
break
```

in this code-

```
    1 import numpy as np
    2 import cv2
    3 
    4 cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    5 
    6 while(True):
    7     # Capture frame-by-frame
    8     ret, frame = cap.read()
    9 
   10     # Our operations on the frame come here
   11     gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   12 
   13     # Display the resulting frame
   14     cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
   15     if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
   16         break
   17 
   18 # When everything done, release the capture
   19 cap.release()
   20 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What does ord('q') and 0xFF mean? How is it being used here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- `ord('q')` returns the Unicode code point of q
- `cv2.waitkey(1)` returns a 32-bit integer corresponding to the pressed key
- `& 0xFF` is a bit mask which sets the left 24 bits to zero, because `ord()` returns a value betwen 0 and 255, since your keyboard only has a limited character set
- Therefore, once the mask is applied, it is then possible to check if it is the corresponding key.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way we can add a pause - play effect?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064777/use-waitkey-in-order-pause-and-play-video

Comment: So, if we do that, then we don't have to add the 0xFF part right?

Comment: It cant hurt to add that part, but for what your doing it should matter.

Comment: @IronVenom just to add my 2 cents, in some systems the waitKey returns the ascii representation of the key pressed and some bits are flipped for alt, ctrl, caps lock and other special keys. This are usually the first bits and that is why the 0xFF is used or sometimes just 255, since it will do a bitwise and and the first bits will be set to 0.

Answer (score 6):

First, `cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF` will be executed.

- Doing wait 1 **ms** for user press.
- If user press, for example, *q* then `waitKey` return `DECIMAL VALUE` of *q* is 113. In **Binary**, It is expressed as **0b01110001**.
- Next, `AND` operator is excuted with two inputs are **0b01110001** and 0xFF (**0b11111111**).

**0b01110001** `AND` **0b11111111** = **0b01110001**. Exactly result is `DECIMAL VALUE` of *q*

Second, compare value of left expression **0b01110001** with `ord('q')`. Clearly, these values is the same as another value. And final result is `break` is invoked.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [`cv2.waitkey` docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#waitkey):

> It returns the code of the pressed key or -1 if no key was pressed
>   before the specified time had elapsed.

Generally in the OpenCV tutorials and blogs, it is a general convention to use "`q`" key for halting any indefinite operation such as *capturing frames from camera in your case.* In your case, the program indefinitely checks at each iteration if "`q`" key is being pressed using `cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q')` statement. If `True` then it simply brakes the infinite `while` loop. You can set it to any key of your choice.